# matplotlib does not plot correctly when data goes to infinity?

Tags: matplotlib

so I was plotting MSE against iterations for a linear regression problem. However, I realised matplotlib was plotting a graph that does not correspond to the data when the data goes to infinity. The rest of the figures it plotted was fine.

Here's the data, I tried to show enough so the trend is visible.

```
Epoch 1 :
Loss= tensor(89.5862, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 2 :
Loss= tensor(89.5847, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 3 :
Loss= tensor(89.5833, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 4 :
Loss= tensor(89.5820, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 5 :
Loss= tensor(89.5807, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 6 :
Loss= tensor(89.5795, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
.
.
Epoch 55 :
Loss= tensor(554.9543, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 56 :
Loss= tensor(958.5474, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 57 :
Loss= tensor(1712.1147, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 58 :
Loss= tensor(3119.1350, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 59 :
Loss= tensor(5746.2451, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
.
.
Epoch 167 :
Loss= tensor(1.0959e+33, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 168 :
Loss= tensor(inf, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 169 :
Loss= tensor(inf, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
.
.
Epoch 199 :
Loss= tensor(inf, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Epoch 200 :
Loss= tensor(inf, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
```

And here's the picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just realised the answer to this question after typing everything out.

Matplotlib didn't plot the graph wrongly, the whole y-axis should be multiplied by `1e33` as indicated by the number on the top-left of the box.

Comment: Such plots are best visualized on a log scale... Use `plt.yscale('log')`